# Tsconfig cannot find imported path

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module, es6-modules

**Hello**

I'm trying to make my project's imports work with typescript import paths. Each time i have this *error : Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'app' imported from dist/index.js*

I have the impression that when compiling node interprets my "app" import path by an external library of node_modules and I don't understand why

**My project structure :**

```
-> src
  -> cards
     index.ts
  -> game
     index.ts
  -> player
     index.ts
  index.ts (entry)
-> dist
tsconfig.ts
package.json
```

When I use relative paths my project like this :
`import { Game } from "./game";`

launches well but as soon as I use typescript import paths it no longer works

**tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "president",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "President - card game",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "author": "Yanis Sahnoune",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "serve:dev": "tsx watch index.ts",
    "start": "rm -rf dist/ && yarn && yarn tsc && node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node dist/index.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules dist && yarn cache clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "linebyline": "^1.3.0",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsx": "^3.12.7",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vitest": "^0.34.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me I am out of solution thank you

I tried using babel like this :
`rm -rf dist/ && yarn && tsc && babel-node --extensions .ts dist/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found my problem.

In my project i use rollup for build my project with javascript ES6. I write in my tsconfig file my aliases but rollup needed config his config parallely typescript. I add in rollup.config.js :

```
{
input: 'src/index.ts',
output: {
    file: 'dist/index.mjs',
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'es',
},
watch: {
    chokidar: true,
    buildDelay: true
},
plugins: [
    typescript(),
    esbuild({
        include: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        minify: true,
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
        sourceMap: true,
    }),
    alias({
        entries:[
            { find: 'app', replacement: './src' },
        ],
        resolve: ['.ts', '.js'],
    })
],
```

}

I had entries and typescript() function from @rollup/plugin-typescript package. It work !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).